# How to filter an array that contains functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, if-statement

so like I'm required to write if/else statement in shorthand or in functions instead of :
if (hero === "Robin"){return callRobin()}... or instead of switch cases.

```
const callRobin = () => `Hey Robin`;
const callRaven = () => `Hey Raven`;
const callStarFire = () => `Hey StarFire`;
const callBeastBoy = () => `Hey BeastBoy`;

// these were the functions!!

const herosFuncArr = [callRobin, callRaven, callStarFire, callBeastBoy];  //an array that contains the functions
const herosStringsArr = ['Robin', 'Raven', 'StarFire', 'BeastBoy'];
const myFunc = param => param == herosStringsArr.filter(x => x.includes(param)) ? herosFuncArr.filter(z => z.name.includes(param)()) : false;
myFunc('StarFire');
```

my point in this code was : when we inter a hero name as a parameter, if it exists in the strings array, return an element from the functions array that has the same letters the parameter have AS A FUNCTION *as indicated with the double parentheses*.

I tried so many things, also tried eval (`call${param}()) but apparently that's unacceptable.
also tried .toString but didn't work (for me).
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `name` property coming from?

Comment: If you need to call functions by evaluating the function name at runtime, you've probably made some severe gaffes in design. I would implore you to take several steps back and understand the requirement itself before you end up with a codebase that is completely unmaintainable long-term (what happens if you end up having to support several hundred, several thousand, or even several *million* of these `heros` values? Do you anticipate actually going in and creating a single function for each of the innumerable heros you'll have?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're far better off eliminating all of those functions, and creating one `callHero` function into which you can pass the name of the found hero and return a string. You don't need to worry about `filter`; use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first match.

And it's best not to use `includes` because that will match `Star` to `StarFire` which you probably don't want to do. Just do a simple comparison instead.

```js
const heroes = ['Robin', 'Raven', 'StarFire', 'BeastBoy'];

// Return a string
function callHero(hero) {
  return `Hey ${hero}!`;
}

function isAHero(name) {

  // Find the hero in the array
  const hero = heroes.find(hero => hero === name);

  // If it exists call the `callHero` function with the hero name
  // and return the resulting string from the function
  if (hero) return callHero(hero);

  // Otherwise return something else
  return `Boo! ${name} is not a hero.`;
}

console.log(isAHero('Robin'));
console.log(isAHero('Billy Joel'));
console.log(isAHero('StarFire'));
console.log(isAHero('Star'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the functions and compare the returned string:

```js
const callRobin = () => `Hey Robin`;
const callRaven = () => `Hey Raven`;
const callStarFire = () => `Hey StarFire`;
const callBeastBoy = () => `Hey BeastBoy`;

// these were the functions!!

const herosFuncArr = [callRobin, callRaven, callStarFire, callBeastBoy];  //an array that contains the functions
const herosStringsArr = ['Robin', 'Raven', 'StarFire', 'BeastBoy'];
const myFunc = param => param == herosStringsArr.filter(x => x.includes(param)) ? herosFuncArr.filter(z => z().includes(param)) : false;

console.log(myFunc('StarFire'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of Map. You should place heroStringsArr as key and your functions as value:

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set('Robin', () => console.log('Hey Robin'));
map.set('Raven', () => console.log('Hey Raven'));
map.set('StarFire', () => console.log('Hey StarFire'));
map.set('BeastBoy', () => console.log('Hey BeastBoy'));

const myFunc = param => map.has(param) ? map.get(param) : console.log('This function is not available!');

myFunc('Robin')();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Andy's idea of *just one function*. Also if you must have many functions, essentially multiple "instances" of the same function, you can start of with an array of strings which you can then map using the *one function* to an array of functions.

You can as well use *regular expressions* as in the demo below:

```js
const callRobin = () => `Hey Robin`;
const callRaven = () => `Hey Raven`;
const callStarFire = () => `Hey StarFire`;
const callBeastBoy = () => `Hey BeastBoy`;

// these were the functions!!

const herosFuncArr = [callRobin, callRaven, callStarFire, callBeastBoy];  //an array that contains the functions
const herosStringsArr = ['Robin', 'Raven', 'StarFire', 'BeastBoy'];
const myFunc = param => herosFuncArr.filter(f => (new RegExp(`\\b${param}\\b`)).test( f() )).length > 0; 
console.log( myFunc('StarFire') );
```